# How to set overflow hidden so that overflows on both sides, element stays centered?

Tags: html, css

[Please take a look at this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dve3413/rxdhcsvc/19/)

You will see the overflow of the inner table goes to the right. I want the overflow to be equal on both sides so that the inner table stays horizontally centered within the TD, even when it is overflowing. (see below)

```css
.outerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="outerTable" width=200px height=200px align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top>
      <table class="innerTable" width=800px height=100px border=1 align=center>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pete, this is not a duplicate question. The question you referenced as duplicate has the innertable within a 'TD' element. This question has the innertable within a 'DIV' element. Not fair to downgrade this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet without adding other `div`s or anything else:

```css
.outerTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.innerTable {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table class="outerTable" width=200px height=200px align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top>
      <table class="innerTable" width=800px height=100px border=1>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I only added CSS for the `innerTable`,
and removed the `overflow: hidden` so that we can see how the `table`s actually are.

Comment: Nice, keep forgetting about translating :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `.outerTable` and add :

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rxdhcsvc/20/) the jsfiddle updated

Comment: That doesn't change the problem, the `td` stays left-aligned, even if it's more complicated to see it because you hide the `overflow`.